# Question about Clear function

Tags: scripting, clear

I have a script starting with Clear ["r*", "data*", "file*"]. Does this clear all variables starting with "r" or "data"or "file"? Also, I would like to know if I define a function with a variable (e.g findn[key_]) and assign a value to that variable using (#); should I clear that function or variable If I use it again in the script? I have to use the script for different cases.

For example, I have the following functions which are used twice in my script. Should I clear "findn" or "Key" before the second time using in the script although the functions are applied on lists with different names.

Function1: (As you see the lists where the function is applied have two different names (i.e assocp and assocn )

```
(*Function 1*)

(*first time:*)
findn[key_] := #[key] & /@ assocp // DeleteMissing;
clustersp = Map[Append[#, First@findn[#]] &, ccmppp, {-2}];

(*Second time:*)
findn[key_] := #[key] & /@ assocn // DeleteMissing;
clustersn = Map[Append[#, First@findn[#]] &, ccmpnn, {-2}];
```

Or

Function2: (As you see the lists where the function is applied have two different names (i.e Normalyp and Normalyn )

```
(*Function2:*)

(*First time:*)
Torso[y_] := If[y < 0.33, L, T - TL];
Torsop = Torso /@ Normalyp;

(*Second time:*)

Torso[y_] := If[y < 0.33, L, T - TL];
Torsop = Torso /@ Normalyn;
```

Comment: A quick experiment: `red = RGBColor[1, 0, 0]; rect = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]; rat =DictionaryLookup["rat"];green = Green;` then do `Clear["re*"]` - it will only Clear `red` and `rect` but not `rat` or `green`. So yes, you are correct about using wildcards in `Clear`. This is in the _>Details_ section here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html

Comment: Could you give a better example of your second problem? If you use a function, the argument isn't permanent. If you set or define a global inside that function (i.e without a With, Block, Module), then yes, you will need to clear it. If you do this for example: `f[x_] := (y = 1+#^2)&@x` then calling `f[1]` will set global y to 2 and return 2. But calling `f[2]` will set a global y to 5 and return 5.

Comment: Thank you flinty! I modified the question. Is there any general simple rule that I know which variables or names should be clear. I am asking as I need to use the script many times. So, I make sure that no variable has assignment from before.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. Let me point out, that it probably is not a good idea to redefine functions like that. For instance it would make sense to define `findn[key_, assoc_] := #[key] & /@ assoc // DeleteMissing`.

Comment: @flinty Thanks a lot! Your explanation was very helpful.